# How Katalon Studio works with the JUnit, testNg?

Tags: junit, testng, katalon-studio

My company has recently started to test the stable release through automation for which we are using the Katalon Studio as an automation tool.

How Katalon Studio works with the JUnit, TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment (Release 5.0.1) it is not possible to import your JUnit/TestNG code to Katalon Studio. Means, you have to write new test scripts. But you can import third party libraries to your code, to do all the automation stuff like in your JUnit test cases.

Comment: can you suggest some third parties libraries which can work me

Comment: It means, that you can import all the Java APIs to Katalon Script, you are using in your JUnit and TestNG test scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom Katalon integration with JUnit4 [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/junit4-katalon-studio-integration-by-a-built-in-keyword/17637).

Besides, starting with version 5.7.0., Katalon Studio has introduced [Cucumber BDD](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/new/version-570.html) support and it is also running on top of JUnit.